# Multiple regex for replacing characters in java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have the following string:

```
String str = "Klaße, STRAßE, FUß";
```

Using of **combined regex** I want to replace German **ß** letter to **ss** or **SS** respectively. To perform this I have:

```
String replaceUml = str
        .replaceAll("ß", "ss")
        .replaceAll("A-Z|ss$", "SS")
        .replaceAll("^(?=^A-Z)(?=.*A-Z$)(?=.*ss).*$", "SS");
```

Expected result:

`Klasse, STRASSE, FUSS`

Actual result:

`Klasse, STRAssE, FUSS`

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you think your expressions do. The first one replaces the ß with `ss`, the second one takes `ss` at the end of a word (or the string `A-Z`) and replaces it with `SS` (which is how `FUSS` happens to be right), but I cannot figure out what you think the third one is supposed to do... Can you clarify?

Comment: @Floris The third one is suppose to find string which starts with Uppercases and ends also with Uppercases and have `ss` inbetween. If all mentioned expressions are true then replace the `ss` to `SS`

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do correctly then you are trying to replace with small `ss` if the string contains only lowercase characters and to upper `SS` if it is all uppercase, the third replace I still can't figure out what you are trying to achieve and you are probably confusing character class ranges with literal character matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String replaceUml = str
    .replaceAll("(?<=\\p{Lu})ß", "SS")
    .replace("ß", "ss")
```

This uses [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with a preceding unicode upper case letter ("SÜß"), to have capital "SS".

The `(?<= ... )` is a look-behind, a kind of context matching. You could also do

```
    .replaceAll("(\\p{Lu})ß", "$1SS")
```

as `ß` will not occure at the beginning.

Your main trouble was not using brackets `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you're trying to match some character in the range A-Z, you need to put it in square brackets.  This

```
.replaceAll("A-Z|ss$", "SS")
```

will look for the three characters A-Z in the source, which isn't what you want.  Second, I think you're confused about what | means.  If you say this:

```
.replaceAll("[A-Z]|ss$", "SS")
```

it will replace *any* upper-case letter at the end of the word with SS, because | means look for this *or* that.

A third problem with your approach is that the second and third replaceAll's will look for any ss that was in the original string, even if it didn't come from a ß.  This may or may not be what you want.

Here's what I'd do:

```
String replaceUml = str
    .replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])ß", "SS")
    .replaceAll("ß", "ss");
```

This will first replace all ß by SS if the character before the ß is an upper-case letter; then if there are any ß's left over, they get replaced by ss.  Actually, this won't work if the character before ß is an umlaut like Ä, so you probably should change this to

```
String replaceUml = str
    .replaceAll("(?<=[A-ZÄÖÜ])ß", "SS")
    .replaceAll("ß", "ss");
```

(There may be a better way to specify an "upper-case Unicode letter"; I'll look for it.)

EDIT:

```
String replaceUml = str
    .replaceAll("(?<=\\p{Lu})ß", "SS")
    .replaceAll("ß", "ss");
```

A problem is that it won't work if ß is the *second* character in the text, and the first letter of the word is upper-cased but the rest of the word isn't.  In that case you probably want lower-case "ss".

```
String replaceUml = str
    .replaceAll("(?<=\\b\\p{Lu})ß(?=\\P{Lu})", "ss")
    .replaceAll("(?<=\\p{Lu})ß", "SS")
    .replaceAll("ß", "ss");
```

Now the first one will replace ß by ss if it's preceded by an upper-case letter that is the first letter of the word but followed by a character that isn't an upper-case letter.  `\P{Lu}` with an upper-case P will match any character other than an upper-case letter (it's the negative of `\p{Lu}` with a lower-case p).  I also included \b to test for the first character of a word.

Comment: +1 but I think you need a look ahead too, in case of `Aßbc` you want `Assbc` (don't know if German words exist with ß second letter, but from a pattern aspect, it's an edge case)

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about it at the same time you were.  And I suspect that words like that do exist where the ß is followed by "t" or "p", but I don't remember for sure, and just to make things interesting the German government recently changed the rules for when you're supposed to use ß, so whatever I learned in high-school German is wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking your regex into parts:

### [Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/oN3rE2)

**Regex**

```
/ß/g
```

***Description***

```
ß Literal ß
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

***Visualization***

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

### [Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/iR0kJ9)

**Regex**

```
/([A-Z])ss$/g
```

***Description***

```
1st Capturing group ([A-Z]) 
    Char class [A-Z]  matches:
        A-Z A character range between Literal A and Literal Z
ss Literal ss
$ End of string
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

***Visualization***

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

### [Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/uZ3sB7)

**Regex**

```
/([A-Z]+)ss([A-Z]+)/g
```

***Description***

```
1st Capturing group ([A-Z]+) 
    Char class [A-Z] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
        A-Z A character range between Literal A and Literal Z
ss Literal ss
2nd Capturing group ([A-Z]+) 
    Char class [A-Z] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
        A-Z A character range between Literal A and Literal Z
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

***Visualization***

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

### Specifically for you

```
String replaceUml = str
    .replaceAll("ß", "ss")
    .replaceAll("([A-Z])ss$", "$1SS")
    .replaceAll("([A-Z]+)ss([A-Z]+)", "$1SS$2");
```

Comment: Ummm, isn't that going to *delete* the character before the ss?

Comment: yeah if you click the links i used the capture groups just didn't in the code for the solution editting

Comment: you need to double-backslash \1 and \2

Comment: This java, not JavaScript

Comment: Yes, I didn't pick up on that earlier.  (Also, it isn't Perl.)  It should be `$1` and `$2`. `\\1` and `\\2` don't work.

Answer (score -1):

Use **String.replaceFirst()** instead of String.replaceAll().

```
replaceAll("ß", "ss")
```

This will replace all the occurrences of "ß". Hence the output after this statement becomes something like this :

> Klasse, STRAssE, FUss

Now `replaceAll("A-Z|ss$", "SS")` replaces the last occurrence of "ss" with "SS", hence your final result looks like this :

> Klasse, STRAssE, FUSS

To get your **expected result** try this out :

```
String replaceUml = str.replaceFirst("ß", "ss").replaceAll("ß", "SS");
```

Comment: With your suggestion I have now following result: `Klasse, STRAssE, FUss`

Comment: try using replaceFirst(). It will help. :-)

Comment: following your answer we have result: `Klasse, STRAssE, FUSS`, but I want `Klasse, STRASSE, FUSS`

Comment: see the last part of my answer. I have pasted the code to get your expected result. Hope this will help.